# Trying to remember a novel with an efficient alien language

Tags: story-identification, novel, languages

I remember reading this science fiction novel several years ago. Here's what I remember (or think I remember) about the story:

- Coded transmissions are intercepted right before assassinations are made
- Involved a linguist who was commissioned to decode the intercepted transmissions
- The linguist figures out that it's actually a language
- The language is so efficient that when the linguist begins thinking in the language, the world seems to slow down
- Space travel is a common thing
- I think an assassination may have been made or attempted against an ambassador

Other than those details, I really can't remember much about the novel except that I really enjoyed it. Does this ring a bell for anybody?

Comment: In a similar vein, some Heinlein short stories feature a group of (exceptional) humans who use a exceedingly compact language as part of their tool kit for being better than the rest of us. "Gulf" is one, and the events therein get a passing mention in *Friday*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds a lot like "[Babel-17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_17)" by Samuel Delany.

Once the linguist protagonist, Rydra Wong, finally figures out the language

> she also realizes merely understanding the language puts you in the mindset to commit the assassinations. Therefore the language itself IS a weapon.

Pretty sure Delany was familiar with the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapir_Whorf), which (in a *very simplified* form) posits that language shapes how you think about the world, and even which thoughts you are capable of.

Comment: That's it! Babel-17! Thank you very much for that!